# Rails 3.2 Mass Assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

I'm hoping I can get some help with a mass assignment issue in my recently upgraded Rails 3.2 app.

I understand that in Rails 3.2 attributes are locked down by default and in order for them to be assigned I need to "unlock" them using attr_accessible.  This works fine for normal model attributes.

However, I have a homegrown custom property mixin that allows me to add arbitrarily named properties to any model.  These properties are stored in the custom_properties table.  This mixin leverages method missing to look for a property from that table if I ask a model for a property like: foo.property_foobar.

Each model that uses this mixin can have X custom properties with arbitrary names.  I don't have the ability to dictate the names of these properties which obviously makes it difficult to add to attr_accessible.

Does anyone have a recommendation on how I can allow mass assignment of these dynamic properties?  I would rather not whitelist all model attributes.

Hopefully all of this makes sense.  Thanks everyone!

Louis

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `attr_protected` instead. This allows you to blacklist some attributes while allowing the rest. However, this is a bit harder to secure.

Another solution is to move assignment protection to the controller and allow/reject attributes as needed in each controller/action. There is a gem called [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) that allows this and it will also be included in Rails 4. I suggest this solution.

If none of the above work for you, maybe you should try another approach to implement those arbitrary attributes? For example, you could instead store them as a serialized hash in a database column.

Comment: Teoulas, thank you very much for your speedy response!  

Regarding attr_protected, I'm assuming you mean turn whitelist off.  I have considered doing this it just makes me feel like I'm doing it wrong if I can't get whitelisting to work.  I'm trying to avoid if possible but given the alternatives may not be able to.

I like your suggestion about re-implementing my custom properties into ActiveRecord:Store.  The issue there is that some of my models that use my custom property mixin are hierarchical: a child inherits a parent's custom property value if the child doesn't have a value (cont...)

Comment: ... this requirement makes it complicated to move to ActiveRecord:Store, although, ultimately it's probably the right move to make.

All that said, I will absolutely look into strong parameters. It sounds like a potential solution if I'm able to permit arbitrarily named properties.  Even still it'd be a significant effort.

Thanks again for your time.  It's greatly appreciated.  Yet another reason why I love RoR!